# Replace the second string in the double quotes with the first string in the double quotes

Tags: awk, sed

I have a CSV file that I want to search and find the first occurrence then replace the second occurrence with the first

Here is an example of courses.csv

```
"Foo","Bar",course foo,Lorem
"Baz","Foo",course bar,Lorem
```

In the above CSV, I want to replace the **second string in the double quotes** with the **first string in the double quotes**

After the operation, the results should be as follow

```
"Foo","Foo",course foo,Lorem
"Baz","Baz",course bar,Lorem
```

How can I achieve this preferably on bash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you'll always want to put the first field in place of the second field, I'd urge you to try the following:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=",";OFS=","}{$2=$1;print $0}' yourfile.csv
```

alternatively

```
awk -v FS="," -v OFS="," '{$2=$1;print $0}' yourfile.csv
```

this is not in-place: that would require some more effort, but the gist is this.